# How can I retrieve file and a json in a single fetch call using flask?

Tags: python, file, flask

I know that I can post a file and some formData in a fetch(POST) call but I am having trouble doing the reverse i.e. to receive a file and some formData values by one fetch (could be POST or GET) call. I am looking for resources and documentation but couldn't find anything as of yet on this. I am able to do this for smaller files by sending them as base64 String but for larger files, i am facing issue. Appreciation for any guidances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert you data into json.

```
 import json



data= 'this is your data'



result = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: we can do that but for bigger file size, it wouldn't so convenient right? @Sankara

Answer (score 0):

Send a JSONResponse with the file URL and other details.
In frontend, render the image with the url. `{{ url_for('static', <from the json>) }}`. (Hope you are saving the static folder)